# CGO binary does not run in OSX

Tags: macos, go

I am facing a weird issue in running a cgo binary in MAC OSX. The binary builds on my first Mac will work on my second Mac but shows `exit status 1` on my first mac. I don't see any difference in `go env`. Is there any way I can debug this issue to understand what is wrong and hopefully fix it? I reinstall os in the first mac. Things started working after that. Then it stopped working. I can build the binary at all time.

Comment: Possibly the majority of go binaries on osx use cgo, so that in itself shouldn't affect your results. What are you doing with cgo? What is showing `exit status 1`? Building the binary on the second machine might show you what shared libs are missing.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess I would say there is likely a missing library. You should use `dtruss myapp` to see what your application is doing right before it exits.